# Default 404 error page instead of custom?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, http-status-code-404

Why this page returns the default 404 page: `http://example.com/this%2Fthis`
but this one returns the custom one: `http://example.com/this/this`
and this one returns the custom one also: `http://example.com/?i=this%2Fthis`

Here is my htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/?id=error
```

In my htaccess, I clearly specify the page all errors should redirect to. In the 1st case, I am getting the default error page and not my custom one.

The question is, what I must add to my htaccess file in order to have the url work properly and redirect to the custom error page?

Comment: @anubhava: yes, the above line is my complete .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to a security reason.

URLs containing `%2f` OR `%5c` characters just return a default `404` from `Apache` for security reasons.

#### [Related Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)

#### [Also see: 5 Solutions to Url Encoded Slashes (%2F) Problem in Apache](http://www.leakon.com/archives/865)

Comment: That is because `%2F` is in query string not in main URI